# Can you help me find an optimal mixed strategy for this simple 2-person allocation game?

Tags: game-theory, infinite-games

Consider the following simple 2-person game.  Players 1 and 2 each have 100 dollar coins, with a barrier between them, hiding each other's moves.  Each player must allocates his 100 coins into 3 piles: A, B, and C.  For example 40 in A, 30 in B, 30 in C.  Then the barrier is removed.  Whichever player has more coins in pile A is the winner of A, same with B and C.  The player who wins the most of the 3 piles is the overall winner.  Obviously, if Player 1's  move is known, Player 2 can allocate his coins to win 2 of the 3 piles, so no pure strategy is optimal.  But if both players' moves are unknown to each other, is there an optimal mixed strategy for allocating between the 3 piles?

Comment: What happens with tied piles?

Comment: I don't follow.  Suppose you know that I will put $30$ coins in pile A.  How can you be certain of winning two piles?

Comment: I think the move consists of placing coins to all piles simultaneously. (so placing $30$ to pile A without placing remaining $70$ is not a complete move)

Answer (score 0):

If I use a strategy that puts all coins on  a single random pile and leaves the other piles empty, and you use a strategy that has a positve probability $p$ of *not* putting all coins on a single pile, then I end up with a minimum of $100$ coins and an expected number of $(1+\frac p3)100$ coins (and accordingly, you end with a maximum of $100$ coins and an expected number of $(1-\frac p3)100$ coins. Hence my strategy is strictly better than any strategy with positive $p$. On the other hand, it ties with every strategy that has $p=0$.

Comment: I believe the score is kept in *piles*, not coins, from my reading of the question.